# How to Render Nested Map Items inside react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I have a react navigation component that is rendered based on some JSON data.

I have sucessfully rendered the top level items, but I'm having trouble rendering the second level sub pages.

This is how I think the code should look I also only want the

tag to be output can someone help me with the syntax to achive this?

```
    {headerData.TopLevelPages.map(toplevelPage => (
        <li key={toplevelPage.Id}>{toplevelPage.NavLinkText}</li>
    
         <ul>//Only out put UL If SubNavMenuItems as items
    
            {toplevelPage.SubNavMenuItems.map(sublevelPage => (
                   <li key={sublevelPage.Id}>{sublevelPage.NavLinkText}</li>
                 ))}
    
        <ul>

   ))}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple recursive function can render a nested menu with any depth.

Try like below.

```js
const headerData = { TopLevelPages: [ { NavLinkText: "Text 1", Id: "1", SubNavMenuItems: [ { NavLinkText: "sub Text 1-1", Id: "1-1" }, { NavLinkText: "sub Text 1-2", Id: "1-2", SubNavMenuItems: [ { NavLinkText: "sub-sub Text 1-2-1", Id: "1-2-1" } ] } ] }, { NavLinkText: "Text 2", Id: "2" } ] };

function App() {
  
  const renderNavMenu = (menus) => {
    return menus.map(({ NavLinkText, Id, SubNavMenuItems }) => (
      <ul>
        {/* render current menu item */}
        <li key={Id}>{NavLinkText}</li>
        {/* render the sub menu items */}
        {SubNavMenuItems && <ul>{renderNavMenu(SubNavMenuItems)}</ul>}
      </ul>
    ));
  };

  return renderNavMenu(headerData.TopLevelPages);
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: @Ayo Adesina, check this out !!

Answer (score 0):

```
    {headerData.TopLevelPages.map(toplevelPage => (
        <li key={toplevelPage.Id}>{toplevelPage.NavLinkText}</li>
    
    { toplevelPage.SubNavMenuItems && 
        ( <ul>//Only out put UL If SubNavMenuItems as items
    
            {toplevelPage.SubNavMenuItems.map(sublevelPage => (
                   <li key={sublevelPage.Id}>{sublevelPage.NavLinkText}</li>
                 ))}
    
        <ul>)
    }

   ))}
```

do a conditional rendering once more

Comment: This doesn't seem to complie, the error is after the first </li> 
Unexpected token, expected ","